# How to read a [nonblocking] filedescriptor of a file that is appended to (aka, like tail -f)?

Tags: linux, file, nonblocking, epoll, libev

Actually, I am using libev; but under the hood this is using epoll (I'm only on linux). When I add a watcher to read a file and all data has been read then I do get a call back that there is data to read, but read(2) returns 0 (EOF). At that point I have to stop the watcher or else it will continue to tell me that there is something to read. However, if I stop the watcher and then some other process appends data to that file then I'll never see it.

What is the correct way to get notified that there is additional/appended data in a file that can be read when before I already read till the end?

I'd prefer the answer in terms of libev, but lower level will do too (I can then probably translate that to how to do that with libev).

Comment: Edge triggered or level triggered? Anyway, looks like you can use `inotify` to monitor the file for changes before issuing another read.

Comment: libev only supports level triggered; but yeah I'm currently looking into adding an inotify fd.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is very common, for some reason, for people to think that making an fd nonblocking, or calling poll/select/.. has different behaviour for files compared to other types of file descriptions, but nonblocking behaviour and I/O readyness behaviour is essentially the same for all of types of file descriptions: the kernel will immediately return from read/write etc. if the outcome is known, and will signal I/O readyness when this is the case. When a socket has an EOF condition, select will signal that the socket is ready to read, and you will get 0 (for EOF). The same happens for files - if you are at the end of a file, the kernel will return immediately from read and return 0 to signal EOF.

The important difference is that files can change contents at random places, and can be extended. Pipes and sockets are not random access and cannot be appended to once closed. Thus, while the behaviour is consistent, it is often not what is wanted, namely waiting for a file to change in some way.

The conflict in many people's minds is simply that they want to be told "when there is new data", but if you think about it a bit, you will realise that simply waking you up would not be an adequate interface for this, as you have no way of knowing why you woke up, and what changed.

POSIX doesn't have an interface to do that, other than regularly polling the fd or file (and in case of random changes, regularly reading the whole file!). Some operating systems have an interface to do something similar to that (kqueue on BSDs, inotify on GNU/Linux) , but they are usually not a perfect match, either (for example, inotify cannot watch an *fd* for changes, it will watch a *path* for changes).

The closest you can get with libev is to use an `ev_stat` watcher. It behaves as if you would `stat()` a path regularly, and invoke the watcher callback whenever the stat data changes. Portably, it does just that: it regularly calls `stat`, but on some operating systems (currently only inotify on GNU/Linux, as kqueue doesn't have correct semantics for this) it can use other mechanisms to speed this up in some cases, although it will fall back to regular `stat` polling everywhere, for example for when the file is on a network file system, where inotify can't see remote changes.

To answer your question: If you have a path, you can use an `ev_stat` watcher to watch for stat data changes, such as size/mtime etc. changes. Doing this right can be a bit tricky (see the libev documentation, especially the part about stat time resolution: http://pod.tst.eu/http://cvs.schmorp.de/libev/ev.pod#code_ev_stat_code_did_the_file_attri), and you have to keep in mind that this watches a *path*, not a *file descriptor*, so you might want to compare the device/inode of your file descriptor and the watched path regularly to see if you still have the correct file open.

This still doesn't tell you what part of the file has changed.

Alternatively, since you apparently only want to read appended data, you could opt to just `read()` the file regularly (in an `ev_timer` callback) and do away with all the complexity and hassles of an `ev_stat` watcher setup (while not forgetting to also compare the path stat data with your fd stat data to see if you still hasve the right file open, depending on whether the file your are reading might get renamed or replaced. Sometimes programs also truncate files, something you can also detect by seeing the size decrease between stat calls).

This is essentially what older `tail -f` implementations do, while newer ones might, for example, take hints (only) from inotify, just like `ev_stat` watchers do.

None of that is easy, and details depend on your knowledge of how exactly the file changes, but it's the best you can do.

Comment: Thank you for the extensive and very complete answer. I suspected that inotify was the (only) way to go because polling on regular intervals isn't an option for me; I'm writing a high performance, event driven library and polling is simply taboo. The reason I ran into this is because the library is kinda fire-and-forget while the real action is executed in a thread pool. So now it can happen that in a single thread you open a file, write to it and then open another file and read from the previous file and then tell the library to clean up as soon as everything is 'done'.

Comment: However, since everything is handled asynchronous, then the reading can start before you even write - or at least read to the end before you're done writing. So for such cases I need an input file that will wait for more data (inotify) until a user defined event happens that tells it that it can stop reading. It's not the most important part of the library but I just want to support it ;).

Comment: I changed the title to have [nonblocking] between square brackets. Thanks.

Comment: Sure - keep in mind, though, that inotify is asynchronous, and cannot tell you what the current situation is, and that it generally only sees local modifications and accesses, so an occasional poll might be prudent. If you know these are non-issues in your environment, then of course you can rely on inotify completely.